# NSMenu with IBAction method for clicking the menu header?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, menu, interface-builder

How can I capture the selection of a NSMenu header with an IBAction method created in connection with interface builder?  I am not sure "header" is the right word so see the image below:

[image]
<sub>(source: [physle.com](http://physle.com/images/NSMenu.jpg))</sub>

Is it possible to create an action for this the way you can with the selection of regular NSMenuItems?  I can create the relationship in interface builder but the method never fires.

Comment: This sounds like a scary idea. Menus don't normally do things themselves.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Do you just want to know when the menu has been shown?

Comment: The application wraps a state machine and I want to setState:NSOnState/NSOffState by querying the machine before displaying the menu

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly, but you can do it.  If you acquire a pointer to the File menu itself, you can give it a delegate object.  One of the methods of the [NSMenuDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMenuDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) is `(void)menuWillOpen:(NSMenu *)menu`.  You could probably use this to achieve the same effect as a target-action mechanism.

Comment: More complicated than I had hoped for but I'm going to give it a shot.

Comment: I could not end up getting this to work and noticed the following note in the docs: "Special Considerations - Do not modify the structure of the menu or the menu items during this method."